# How can I change my recursive code to connect all tiles without crossing a tile more than once?

Tags: swift, recursion

Here's a picture of what I am trying to make my Swift code do:

[image]

I have marked the tiles with numbers. Tile 3 and 8 is disabled. 6 is the starting point and 0 is the goal.

**NOTE:** The start point is specified but the end point is not. End point can be any where as long as the path goes through all the tiles. In my example, I just specified 0 to make it easy but it's not actually going to be specified.

I am only allowed to go horizontal or vertical. There's more than one way to get to the goal but I need to find the path which goes through all numbers once. I have marked this path in the image (6,7,4,5,2,1,0).

Right now I have the following code which first gets all the direct connections of each tile then uses recursion to find the path. Currently my code gives me the path 6,7,4,1,0 which doesn't go through 5 & 2 and hence isn't what I want.

I am not sure how to change my code to get the path which goes through all tiles.

```
let size = (rows: 3, columns: 3)
let off = [3,8]
let start : Int = 6
let finish : Int = 0
var connections = [Int:[Int]]()
var path = [Int]()
var visited = [Int]()

func backtrackingStuff() {
    
    for index in 0..<size.rows * size.columns {
        if !off.contains(index) {
            
            let rowStart : Int = index - index%size.columns
            let rowEnd : Int = rowStart + size.columns - 1
            
            var temp = [Int]()
            let possibleUpperConnection : Int = index - size.columns
            if possibleUpperConnection >= 0 && !off.contains(possibleUpperConnection) {
                temp.append(possibleUpperConnection)
            }
            let possibleBottomConnection : Int = index + size.columns
            if possibleBottomConnection <= (size.rows * size.columns - 1) && !off.contains(possibleBottomConnection) {
                temp.append(possibleBottomConnection)
            }
            
            let possibleLeftConnection : Int = index - 1
            if possibleLeftConnection >= rowStart && !off.contains(possibleLeftConnection) {
                temp.append(possibleLeftConnection)
            }
            
            let possibleRightConnection : Int = index + 1
            if possibleRightConnection <= rowEnd && !off.contains(possibleRightConnection) {
                temp.append(possibleRightConnection)
            }
            
            connections[index] = temp
        }
    }
    
    print("V: \(NSSet(array: Array(connections.keys)))")
    
    getPaths(currentPosition: start)
    
    print("Path: \(path)")
}

func getPaths (currentPosition : Int) -> Bool {
    
    //if NSSet(array: possiblePath).isEqual(to: NSSet(array: Array(connections.keys)) as! Set<AnyHashable>) { {
    if currentPosition == finish {
        path.insert(currentPosition, at: 0)
        return true
    }
    
    visited.append(currentPosition)
    
    if let connectionsForThisIndex = connections[currentPosition] {
        for newIndex in connectionsForThisIndex {
            if !visited.contains(newIndex) {
                if getPaths(currentPosition: newIndex) {
                    path.insert(currentPosition, at: 0)
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return false
}
```

Comment: Is the start/end point specified, or is that also up for you to determine?

Comment: @Alexander the start point is specified but the end point is not. End point can be any where as long as the path goes through all the tiles. In my example, I just specified 0 to make it easy but it's not actually going to be specified.

Comment: got it! I can take a stab at this later

Comment: @Alexander thank you! I will wait.

Comment: @Alexander Hey, sorry to bother you. Were you able to give it a shot?

Comment: Oh hey. It's no bother. This fell off my radar, I had a busy weekend. Could you ping me in about 3 hours?

Comment: I don't quite understand this code's design, could you explain it? `backtrackingStuff` isn't called anywhere

Comment: @Alexander the code is swift code being run on iOS. So the backtrackingStuff gets called from the viewDidLoad method. I didn’t include that because it didn’t seem relevant to it.

Comment: Are the various values that `backtrackingStuff` method access direct members of the VC?

Comment: Yes they are instance variables which you can see at the top of my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189898/discussion-between-alexander-and-pranoy-c).